# Trying to read Integer from JSON file in java

Tags: java, json, int

I am trying to read a JSON file to create a new Object. I can read all the Strings in it but i throws a ClassCastException when trying to read an int. Here is the JSON file.

```
{"id1" : "string1", 
 "id2": "string2",            
 "id3": 100.0
}
```

And here is the java code.

```
public static Aparelho novoAparelho(JSONObject obj) {

    Aparelho ap = null;

        String tipe = (String) obj.get("id1");
        String name = (String) obj.get("id2");


        if(tipe.equals("anyString")) {
            int pot = (int) obj.get("id3");
            ap = new SomeObject(name, pot);
        }

    return ap;
}
```

It throws.
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to `double` first:

```
int pot = (int) (double) obj.get("id3");
ap = new SomeObject(name, pot);
```

Confusingly, there are three kinds of casts:

- Those that convert values of primitives
- Those that change the type of a reference
- Those that box and unbox

In this case, you have an `Object` (which is actually a boxed `Double`), and you want a primitive int. You can't unbox and convert with the same cast, so we need two casts: first from `Object` to `double` (unboxing), and one from `double` to `int` (conversion).

Answer (score 0):

Integers don't have decimal points.

You should be parsing for an int instead of casting as an int.

For example:

```
if (tipe.equals("anyString")) {
    String pot = obj.get("id3");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(pot);
    ap = new SomeObject(name, x);
}
```

Comment: if i remove the decimal poit the exception is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: @alterardm3dm3 Do it using the cast method in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that the field is supposed to be an `int`, you can take advantage of the JSONObject api to handle the parsing for you:

```
        if(tipe.equals("anyString")) {
            int pot = obj.getInt("id3");
            ap = new SomeObject(name, pot);
        }
```

This is a bit more robust than the casting method -- if somebody changes the json that gets passed to you, the accepted answer might break.